# What is an industry of 'hiring freelancers' called?

Tags: word-usage

I am preparing for a personal interview where I am supposed to tell about my experience in several fields like healthcare, gambling etc. But, I don't know whether there's one word for the industry of 'hiring freelancers.'

I can specify a little, I made a website where one can hire freelancers for their jobs.

Comment: Can you clarify? The context you've provided isn't exactly easily reconciled with the example and description you've provided. The only term that comes to mind is `outsourcing`, which simply refers to the practice of contracting work that a firm might do itself to a third party. You could also describe yourself as a `contractor`.

Comment: *Freelance* refers to someone who works on a project-by-project basis: not a full-time employee and not receiving projects through an agency. I have a hard time understanding how gambling or healthcare would apply, but this may be a cultural misunderstanding— professional gamblers in the U.S. don't typically work for third parties, and no medical practitioner would ever refer to him- or herself as a *freelancer*, as it would have negative connotations of amateurishness, disengagement, or neophytism among others. Consider looking up *contracting* or *independent consultant* which may be better.

Comment: Healthcare and gambling are just example type of fields where I worked. The outsourcing good option.

Comment: Did I read it *experience in healthcare and gambling.... and then making a website?* Are you talking about your experience in **making websites** for several industries such as healthcare, gambling? Because if you are an experienced person in gambling, I'm not sure who's taking an interview! But yes, if you have **made websites** on freelancing, gambling and healthcare, someone must be willing to take you as a good web developer! Whichever the case, all the best for your interview! :)

Comment: yes. I made websites for this industries. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an industry of hiring freelancers. A freelancer can work for any industry, and are normally hired by the company or person that had a job needing done.

There are recruiters, who find potential candidates for positions within companies (freelance/contact, temporary, or regular employee), and there are employment agencies or "temp" agencies who have a pool of employees they use to fill the same types of jobs but remain employed by the agency and not the company whose positions are being filled.

But the website you describe I think is best described as you did: a website to help companies or people find freelancers.

Comment: I would like found one word =).

Comment: It's very similar to saying, "What is the industry for hiring employees called?" That's not an industry, that's something done by every industry.